# Issuer certificate issue for Prisma generate or prisma -v command

Tags: node.js, ssl-certificate, prisma

Whenever I am trying to run "prisma generate or prisma -v" I am getting error : Request to https://binaries.prisma.sh/all_commits/0362da...... failed,reason : unable to get local issuer certificate

I already tried setting strictSSL to false.
I'm using next.js and typescript with prisma.
All version are upto dated with prisma.

I am working in a corporate network. Is there any solution in that respect?
Don't recommend github discussion pages i hv tried all none of are working.
Please one knows please answer me. I got struck for a week please answer as soon as possible.

Operating system:Windows 10

Comment: I don't think this is a `git`question.

Comment: yaa my mistake @eftshift if u know can u answer please?

Comment: I don't.... When somebody knows the answer, they will post it.